# CRC Setup, virtualization

Tags: openshift, virtualbox, rhel9

I am trying to install OpenShift CRC on RHEL 9, the problem occures on the step:

```
INFO Setting up virtualization
You need to enable virtualization in BIOS
```

The problem is that virtualization is enabled, but I am not using RHEL 9 as OS installed on a laptop, instead I use Virtual Box.

I would like to know how to fix this, because I can not proceed and can not run `crc start`

Comment: CRC works by creating a virtual machine (and installing OpenShift into that virtual machine). While it is possible to [enable nested virtualization in VirtualBox](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/nested-virt.html), your experience will probably be suboptimal. If you want to use CRC, your best option is to install it on a bare metal host.